# Multilingual Application

Tags: asp.net

i am so much eager to develop the multilingual application. But i don't know how to start.
how to create the application can i  know what is the process to create the application.
other wise give me a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASP.NET Globalization and Localization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try the Nativer SDK: https://github.com/Transround/NativerSDK

It gives multilingual machine translation for 40+ languages within minutes. Also it makes possible to change the resource file in live application while it is being used. 
So you don't need to create resource files for those languages at all. Translation will get directly to your app user's phone from the cloud via the SDK.

For example if your user have german language set on the phone he will get the german translation at first usage after your app with this SDK was integrated and published.

Integration is very easy and takes only 1-2 minutes if you use Android Studio. You should use this plugin: https://github.com/Transround/NativerSDK/tree/master/tools/nativer-admin-plugin-android-studio